Switching bistable relay with BC337 transistor
I do have two bistable relays which do the same: They are either set or reset via a GPIO pin of an ESP32 using a BC337 transistor. A BC337-16 gives me about 120-130 mA with 390R, so that is suitable.
The collector is connected to ground and the emitter to the relay coil (-).
However, in another thread a user pointed out that would be wrong, but I still don't understand why. I tested it on the breadboard and it works as intended, I measure about 120–130 mA. In the opposite direction it seems that I would get a short.


Here my breadboard. The LED is only symbolic instead of a relay, as the current would be too high:


It works (sort-of) because it's possible to abuse a BJT by connecting it backwards, and it'll still (sort-of) function.

@brhans I added now a photo of my breadboard setup. Is this equivalent to my schematic, so also connected backwards?

You are using the transistors in reverse-active or reverse-saturation mode, which is less effective than the standard forward mode. You would need less current from your micirocontroller if you swap collector and emitter to their normal orientation.

What makes you believe that there would be a short when the transistor is used the correct way around, with emitter to ground? Is it the diode-like arrow in its symbol?

@JonathanS. Seems it was the huge difference, I then need a way higher resistor. I tested it now on the breadboard with a BC337-16 and 3.3V, while the LED is driven by 5V. I get ~ 100 mA for the LED with 4.7K Ohm and still 22mA with 22K Ohm. 100K Ohm gives me 4.8 mA for the LED.

Your test circuit with the LED is slightly wrong. The transistor (when used the correct way around) operates as a switch, which means that when you switch it on properly, the LED is connected directly across 5V - without a resistor limiting the current through the LED. That's why the current is essentially unlimited.
You need to do it like this if you want to switch a LED with a NPN transistor:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
For the relay coil, R1 isn't needed as the coil itself limits the current.

The correct way to use an NPN transistor is the mode where collector and base currents go into the transistor, and emitter current comes out.
Which means, relay coil gets 5V, coil connects to collector, and emitter is grounded. Base current and base-emitter voltage is driven from MCU through the resistor.
If you swap the emitter and collector terminals, it can work but poorly, and for voltage between emitter and base, you are hitting the absolute maximum Vebo voltage of 5V. It means that with say 12V coil voltage, the transistor could have damaged and maybe damaged the MCU too.

You show one end of each coil connected to +5 V.  For this configuration, the "correct" approach is to drive each coil with an NPN saturated switch to GND.  Each emitter to GND, each collector to the other end of a coil.
The transistor is indeed trying to create a short to GND.  The transistor collector current is limited by the resistance of the relay coil.
An old and outdated rule of thumb is that to assure "firm" saturation, with the lowest possible voltage across the collector-emitter, the base current should be at least 1/10th the collector current.  This idea is from the 1950's, when power transistor gains really sucked.  Nowadays, with modern components, I think 1/20th is a safe value.  With a high-gain part like the 337, 1/50 probably would be fine.  I'll probably get some grief for that last part.

I think now I slowly understand it, as the +5 V come from the coil  So as the NPN transistor is (in my brain) from "right to left" (while right is GND and left is +5V) it must collect the GND on pin 1, which is the collector. I didn't even know it would work in the opposite direction.

@Tintenfisch Outside of unusual circumstances, you usually want to connect an NPN transistor's emitter to the lowest potential in the circuit (sometimes through a resistor).

No resistor in this case.
